# how can we change the either value or key of the hash map?

Tags: java

Suppose that we have a **Hash Map** with some key value pair and we want to modify either key or value of the **Hash Map** .So how can we do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For changing the value just use

```
map.put(key,newValue);
```

for changing the key use

```
ValueType value = map.get(oldKey);
map.remove(oldKey);
map.put(newKey, value);
```